# Is it possible to vectorise an operation on an array that depends on the position or index of each element?

Tags: r, arrays, performance, vectorization

Let us suppose that I want to perform this operation on a vector:

```r
TEST.1 <- runif(10000, min = 0, max = 10000)  # Whatever, doesn't mind
TEST.2 <- array(0, dim = 10000)  # To save the results

for(i in 1:10000) TEST.2[i] <- TEST.1[i]/i
```

The point is that the index or position of the elements of the array is involved in the operation to be performed on each element.

**Can I vectorise such an operation somehow?**

Comment: Yes.  `i <- 1:10000; TEST.2 <- TEST.1/i`.

Answer (score 4):

The `seq_along` function returns an index of 1 to the length of a vector.

So

```
TEST.2 <- TEST.1 / seq_along(TEST.1)
```

gives you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

Test.2 <- as.array(TEST.1/1:10000)

Comment: When I’m doing operation involving mixtures of math and the infix sequence operator, I try to always surround the sequence triplet with parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do

```
TEST.2 <- TEST.1 / (1:n)
```

This is a lot faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)

n <- 1000000
TEST.1 <- runif(n, min = 0, max = n)  # Whatever, doesn't mind
TEST.2 <- array(0, dim = n)  # To save the results

microbenchmark({for(i in 1:n) TEST.2[i] <- TEST.1[i]/i},
               times=5)
microbenchmark({TEST.2 <- TEST.1 / (1:n)},
               times=5)
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                            expr      min       lq     mean
 {     for (i in 1:n) TEST.2[i] <- TEST.1[i]/i } 55.70905 56.03472 61.05193
   median       uq      max neval
 57.76358 66.06474 69.68756     5
Unit: milliseconds
                           expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq
 {     TEST.2 <- TEST.1/(1:n) } 2.563011 2.66718 2.703565 2.702002 2.725995
      max neval
 2.859639     5
```